# Adding image next to jQuery Mobile Select Menu

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to add an icon of some kind next to a jQuery Mobile select menu in the image below? If so, what would be the image size required? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I posted an answer, but if you post your code for the list your using, or even better, set up a jsfiddle/jsbin, people will be able to provide you with working examples of the answer based on your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add icons to just about anything by adding the following parameters to the element you want to icon to appear within:

```
 data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left"
```

Where `arrow-l` specifies an arrow pointing left.

If you want to specify your own icon/image rather than use one provided by jQuery Mobile, then you can add an image inside the li (before your text), with a class of either `ui-li-icon` or `ui-li-thumb` :

```
<li>
    <img src="images/gf.png" alt="France" class="ui-li-icon">
    <a href="#">Social Triangle</a>
</li>
```

[ui-li-icon](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/lists/lists-icons.html), appears to be restricted to 16px X 16px, and uses the following css conditions:

```
ui-li-icon {
max-height: 16px;
max-width: 16px;
}
```

[ui-li-thumb](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html), appears to be restricted to 80px X 80px, and uses the following css conditions:

```
.ui-li-thumb {
max-height: 80px;
max-width: 80px;
}
```

If you take a look at the above links to the jQuery Mobile documentation, it shows you how to use them in more detail, just check the source: